# React.js. Когда использовать компонент?

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

Чем руководствоваться при создании компонента в react? Его функциональностью и изменяемостью или логической структурой приложения?

Допустим, имеется главная страница

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Блок 1 и блок 3, как понимаю, однозначно должны описываться как компоненты, потому что представляют собой функциональные блоки.

Блоки 2 - входят в навбар и тоже описываются как компоненты.

Блок 3 - отдельный компонент,  содержит дудл, строку поиска и кнопки поиска. Строка поиска и кнопки это отдельные компоненты? А нужно ли выделять дудл в отдельный компонент (допустим он никогда не меняется)?

Блок 4 - футер. Описывать его отдельным компонентом, если он всегда неизменен? Или его включать в компонент, который описывает целиком главную страницу?

Comment: @OlmerDale хочу хотя бы пояснения к моим вопросам. если конкретнее, как стоит разбивать на компоненты? по функциональности или логической структуре. допустим, есть статическая страница с кучей инфы и одной кнопкой. кнопку описываем компонентом, а все остальное в jsx?

Comment: Добавлю также ссылку на документацию: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html

Comment: И на очень полезную статью: https://camjackson.net/post/9-things-every-reactjs-beginner-should-know

Comment: В общем если у вас все хорошо организовано с точки зрения структуры и тулинга, то не нужно бояться делать компоненты маленькими и очень маленькими, даже если вы скорее всего не будете их менять и повторно использовать. Это разделение нужно в том числе для того чтобы о компонентах легче было думать

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму оке, как понимаю, из ссылок максимальная расщепление на компоненты приветствуется (кнопка, строка поиска, тулбар, тайтл), чтобы не запихивать всю верстку в jsx одного компонента

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму и если применить к реальному проекту, который хочу перевести на реакт http://mendeleev.ravecat.ru/ я его грубо могу разбить так http://imgur.com/a/XRJsi ? как понимаю, в 3 и 6 будут еще присутствовать компоненты, которые опишут элементы. а 4 также можно разбить на отдельные? а все эти компоненты вписываются в отдельный большой App, который представляет главную страницу

Comment: @while1pass, да, приветствуется. У меня для себя эмпирическое правило, если я быстрым первым взглядом на метод render не могу понять что в нем происходит, то бью на компоненты. Как побить конкретно ваше существующее приложение мне сейчас думать лень =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Контейнер (`container` или умный компонент)** - это компонент унаследованный от `Component` и содержащий логику и/или изменяющий свое состояние. Используется для порождения и инициализации других компонентов. Его так же можно назвать `statefull`.
- **Презентационный (`presentational` или глупый компонент)** - это компонент унаследованный от `Component` не имеющий логики и не изменяющий свое состояние. Может иметь собственные стили. Так же его называют еще `stateless`. Применяется для отображения данных, как правило полученных через `props`.  Сейчас его использовать нет смысла, так как для его замены был создан новый вид компонентов описываемый ниже.
- **Функциональные (или глупые компоненты так же являющиеся презентационными)** - это компоненты-функции которые не имеют логики и не хранят состояние и имеют собственные стили. Так же называются `stateless`. В их обязанность входит отображать данные полученные через `props`.
- **Чистый (pure)** - компонент унаследованный от `PureComponent`, может относится как к первой категории так и второй и третей. В его задачу входит производить неглубокое сравнение состояния компонента чтобы избежать лишнего рендера и избавить программиста от написания лишней проверки.

Этого должно хватить для понимания где что и когда использовать, но все равно добавлю, что лучше писать как можно меньше компонентов-контейнеров.

Что касается понимания когда использовать компонента, а когда элемент, то проще объяснить на простом примере -

```
// так можно, но лучше не делать
<div className="button-group">
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
</div>


// так будет более правильно
const ButtonGroup = ({children}) => 
  (<div className="button-group">{children}</div>);

<ButtonGroup>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
</ButtonGroup>
```

И раз уж зашел разговор о компонентах, то не могу не упомянуть о такой важной составляющей, как стиль компонентной композиции. Очень часто я вижу подобное -

```
<App>
  <Header/>
  <Footer/>
</App>
```

Но лично я предпочитаю и поэтому советую писать вот так -

```
<App>
  <Header>
    <ButtonGroup>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </ButtonGroup>
  <Header/>
  <Footer>
    <ButtonGroup>
      <button></button>
      <button></button>
    </ButtonGroup>
  <Footer/>
</App>
```

Ведь очень часто бывает так, что из головы вылетают детали собственного приложения и очень важно суметь освежить его в памяти одним охватом. А для людей которые впервые знакомятся с кодом второй вариант вообще подарок, так как очень сложно воссоздать в голове приложение не по дереву, а по классам из файлов. Но есть исключения, когда кода будет действительно много, то придется делать как в первом варианте, но все равно стараться как можно больше уместить в одном компоненте. Просто очень часто вижу как пишут App => Header + Footer. Идешь в Header, а там только один компонент, как например ButtonGroup. Потом идешь в этот ButtonGroup а там ещё один компонент. И так пока дойдешь до последнего уже забываешь откуда пришел и зачем.

А что качается конкретно Вашего случая, то минимум мог бы выглядеть так -

```html
<App>
    <Footer>
        <ButtonGoup>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </ButtonGoup>
        <ButtonGoup>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
            <button></button>
        </ButtonGoup>
    </Footer>
    <Group>
        <Logo/>
        <Search>
            <TextInput></TextInput>
            <KeyboardInput></KeyboardInput>
            <VoiceInput></VoiceInput>
        </Search>
    </Group>
    <Nav>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
        <button></button>
    </Nav>
</App>
```

Comment: и если применить к реальному проекту, который хочу перевести на реакт http://mendeleev.ravecat.ru/ я его грубо могу разбить так http://imgur.com/a/XRJsi ?  как понимаю, в 3 и 6 будут еще присутствовать компоненты, которые опишут химические элементы. а 4 также можно разбить на отдельные? а все эти компоненты вписываются в отдельный большой App, который представляет главную страницу

Comment: <Logo/> , как понимаю, будет staless-компонентом, так как не имеет логики, просто отображает данные (картинку)?

Comment: button это элементы виртуального DOM. В примере с logo это может быть и svg и картинка и слово, но конкретно в случаи google это был бы умный компонент, ведь иногда там и видео с контролом бывает и интерактивная анимация. Что конкретно по таблице, то нет в таких случаях все в одно не пишут, надеюсь Вы прочитали дополнение, где я как раз упомянул такие случаи. Ну а по расчленению таблицы в реальности там будет намного больше компонентов, раза в  3-4 минимум.

Comment: спасибо за пояснения, они очень полезные

Comment: @OlmerDale, хотел бы у вас уточнить, почему `stateful`l компоненты должны быть без стилей, а `stateless` могут быть со стилями? Я не смог понять принципиальной разницы, между наличием состояния и стилями :(

Comment: @RomanAndreev, действительно погорячился, удалил :)

Answer (score 2):

Разделение компонента

Чтобы компонент не делал слишком много. Общепринято делить его на два компонента, каждый из которых будет играть различную роль. Эти два типа компонентов называются компоненты-контейнеры и презентационные компоненты, также их называют “умными” и “глупыми” компонентами соответственно.

Говоря кратко, компоненты-контейнеры содержат исходные данные и работают с состоянием. Состояние передается презентационным компонентам как свойство и затем рендерится в представление.

Термины “умные” и “глупые” компоненты постепенно уходят из употребления в сообществе.

**Презентационные компоненты**

```
var UserList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul className="user-list">
        {this.props.users.map(function(user) {
          return (
            <li key={user.id}>
              <Link to="{'/users/' + user.id}">{user.name}</Link>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

> Презентационные компоненты “глупые” в том смысле, что они не имеют понятия о том, откуда взялись свойства, которыми они оперируют. Состояние? Нет, не слышали.

Презентационные компоненты никогда не должны менять данные в свойствах самостоятельно. Фактически, любой компонент, принимающий свойства должен считать, что данные неизменны и принадлежат его родителю. В то же время никак не влияя на значимость данных в свойстве, он свободен в форматировании данных для вывода в представлении (например, конвертируя Unix timestamp во что-то более читаемое).

**Компоненты-контейнеры**

Компоненты-контейнеры практически всегда являются родительскими для презентационных компонентов. В определенной степени они служат посредниками между презентационными компонентами и остальным приложением. Они также называются “умными” компонентами, так как они в курсе всего приложения в целом.

```
var React = require('react');
var axios = require('axios');
var UserList = require('../views/list-user');

var UserListContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var _this = this;
    axios.get('/path/to/user-api').then(function(response) {
      _this.setState({users: response.data})
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (<UserList users={this.state.users} />);
  }
});

module.exports = UserListContainer;
```

Компоненты-контейнеры могут создаваться точно также, как и любой другой компонент React. У них также, как у остальных компонентов, есть метод render, но они ничего не создают для своего рендеринга, а вместо этого возвращают результат в виде презентационного компонента.

[Ссылка на оригинальную статью](http://prgssr.ru/development/pogruzhenie-v-react-kontejnery.html)

Comment: Минус мой, за то что на мой взгляд достаточно было ссылки в комментариях. Зачем ответ который полная копипаста?

Comment: @stack-it ловите компенсационный плюс. *Надеюсь первоисточник разрешил вам его цитировать в таких объемах*

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму ссылку я мог бы оставить, а если статью удалят , что тогда ? какой прок от ссылки?