# Когда имеет смысл выносить код в отдельный компонент?

Tags: reactjs

ИМХО: получение данных из компонента довольно затратная операция (нужно передавать callback родителя, учитывать структуру данных и т.д.)

поэтому имеет смысл создавать дочерние компоненты только для отображения данных

например:

```
class ItemsList extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return(
        <div>         
            <ul>
                <Item name="Item1" />
                <Item name="Item2" />
...
```

но в большинстве случаев код `Item` довольно тривиален:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <li>{this.props.name}</li>;
      }
    }
```

тогда возникает вопрос, зачем создавать компонент для 1-2х строк HTML-кода, если их можно разместить в родителе?

Comment: "ИМХО: получение данных из компонента довольно затратная операция" - нет. Это экономия на спичках которая оборачивается усложнением кода. Узкое место таки обычно голова программиста. Запись в дом узкое место. Создание пары-трйоки небольших js-объектов в памяти - обычно не узкое место.

Comment: Рекомендую использовать stateless functional components для таких простых штук (с реакта 0.14)
const Item = props => <li>{props.name}</li>, в них по слухам даже есть какой-то микровыигрыш в перформансе

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc

Comment: Но конкретно в этом примере можно элемент списка и не выносить в компонент офк, он еще не усложнился на мой вкус)

Comment: Рекомендую также посмотреть этот вопрос-ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618640/react-js-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, в более сложных компонентах чем `Item`, Вы сохраняете данные в `дочернем` или в `родительском` компоненте? например `input` куда сохранять?

Comment: ну да, работа с формами в реакте осложняется, потому что компоненты форм по своей природе стейтфул. Для работы с этим используется паттерн controlled components (ну то есть да, в дочернем). Подробнее тут: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms. 
Но опять же, если у вас компонент просто форма отвечающая за объект одной степени вложенности, то можно на мелкие кусочки не дробить.

Comment: Best practices - они такие. Это всегда компромисс между двумя стульями: то ли множество бесполезных кусочков и мешающиеся абстракции (а у любой абстракции есть цена), то ли глобальный ужасный объект при взгляде на список состояний которого становится нехорошо

Comment: Я где-то уже писал свое эмпирическое правило: если я за полминуты плохо понимаю что происходит в компоненте, значит что-то пошло не так и возможно пора бить.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, видел Ваше изречение и согласен с ним https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/618640/react-js-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, как Вы получаете данные из `input-дочки` при обработки в родителе? я знаю только такой способ: при создании дочки предать в неё callback или state родителя, и уже сама дочка будет вносить изменения в родителя, но тогда я возвращаюсь к началу своего вопроса, зачем создавать дочку если она все равно пишет в родителя? только изза `деструктуризация` большого компонента? ведь по сути дочка жестка привязывается в родителю и  повторно может быть использована только в похожем компоненте

Comment: 1). Суть при разбиении на компоненты не только и не столько повторное использование, сколько уменьшение количества вещей о которых приходится думать при работе над компонентами. То есть разбивать на штуки о которых проще думать. Это раз.
2) Все обычно колбек прокидывают, это нормальаня практика.  Прокидывать пропсом штуку чтобы потом ее мутировать - категорически не рекомендуется. Пропсы считаются иммутабельными, и с какйо-то версии кажется физически морозятся

Comment: 3). Если вам много надо с формами работать, то есть тележка всяческих оберток. Самая распространенная - redux-form, но лично у меня с ней опыт весьма печален

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, есть ли возможности в компонент другой компонент передать? например: есть компонент popupDialog (единый подход для всего сайта), но на каждой странице свое содержимое

Comment: компонент - это физически просто навороченный js-объект, так что да, разумеется такая возможность есть. Можно компоненты-контейнеры писать типа <Container><Item/><Item/></Container> и обращаться к итемам внутри контейнера как к this.props.children. Но для всяких модальных окон которые одинаковы везде полезно использовать паттерн "портал" - это когда компонент рендерит себя в другую часть дома. Подробнее читать например тут: https://habrahabr.ru/company/smartprogress/blog/306096/

Comment: В общем компонент пропсами прокидывать иногда нужно, но для всяких модальных окон-сообщений почему бы просто не импортировать в нужном месте а не везде пропсами таскать?

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУкрываться не могли бы Вы оформить все Ваши комментарии в один отличный ответ

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach, не, мне лень

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУкрываться =))